# Using Eclipses Progress Monitor Window in a standalone Application

Tags: java, swt, jface, progressmonitor

I'm writing an SWT/JFace application and was wondering if it is possible to use the Progress Monitor Window from Eclipse in my standalone application. For clarification: I'm speaking of this:

[image: Progress Window]

and not the `ProgressMonitorDialog`.

If this is not easily achievable, what would be an easy way to implement this for my own?

Comment: There is no "easy" way to use this component. You will have to implement all required interfaces for your job class and anything that this component requires. Also you need to set up a eclipse rcp or plugin project with all dependencies and anything. It can be done though. Also there is allways the way to simply use all the swt controls to implement this yourself if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```java
Dialog.getBlockedHandler().showBlocked(IProgressMonitor, IStatus, String)
```

I have used it in the past to show that a job of mine needs to wait for another job to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think this dialog is org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog

Although you won't be able to use it directly, you could download the source from Eclipse.org or via the Source link on this page:

http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/eclipse/eclipse-3.5.2/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.html